# prohibited audio/video formats/codecs in App Store

Tags: ios, audio, video, codec

What audio/video formats/codecs are prohibited in App Store?
I'm know only one - aac. Are there any other prohibited formats?

Comment: What do you mean by "prohibited"? Or why would AAC be prohibited anyway?

Comment: I mean application, that support this format will be rejected from App Store. And many applications removed support of AAC-format (see "GoodPlayer" for example). So question is about what formas are prohibited in App Store?

Comment: I've changed topic name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm under the impression that the 'less supported' format is actually AC3 (aka A/52) and other [Dolby codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_AC-3).

> "***AC3, E-AC3 and TrueHD*** support has been removed in almost all video
>   player apps for iOS due to high licensing fee from Dolby (?)" (via [Tech Hints](http://iermolenko.wordpress.com/2012/12/19/ac3-e-ac3-and-truehd-support-has-been-removed-in-almost-all-video-player-apps-for-ios-due-to-high-licensing/))

It seems that Cineplayer is the only player who has licensed these codecs.

Players without AC3 support: [It's Playing](http://www.itsplayingapp.com/faq.html#drawer_faqAudioPlayback), OPlayer, [GoodPlayer](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=16260588&postcount=792), AcePlayer, BuzzPlayer. (links here are to comments from the app publishers).

[AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aac#iTunes_and_iPod) is the [preferred alternative codec](http://www.iphonelife.com/blog/87/tutorial-adding-future-proof-aac-audio-ac-3-only-video-files).

I was unable to quickly find an IOS relevant press release, sorry, but I read along the way that [Blackberry chose to license AC3](http://crackberry.com/rim-settles-patent-lawsuit-dolby-agrees-pay-royalties) in 2011 for an estimated $15m.  I don't think the license is still current.

Comment: I'm not aware of other practical (ie. do people want it?) licensing considerations - I'm sure there are many codecs which require licensing, so are not included, (not sure how many apps support http://forums.divx.com/divx/topics/divx_app_for_ios for instance). Another considerations is: is the codec suited to the device, eg: mkv can work to an extent due to hardware limitations, but full HD mkv with multiple streams are problematic, I believe.